# Can't fill areas of a purchased vector image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, fill

I purchased a vector image from vectorstock.com but I cannot fill some of the areas on it.

This is the image I purchased:

[image]

What happens is when I set a fill it only makes an outline of the triangle.
I want to put a fill color on the *inside triangles* (the ones with gray border).

When I try to fill it this is what happens:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock vector artwork is often all outlined; which means all strokes, or "outlines" have been converted to filled shapes, so anything that isn't already filled can't be filled simply by setting a color on an object; you need to manually fill it somehow...

The easiest way to do that in Illustrator is probably with the Shape Builder tool...

1. Select the object which you want fill the empty spaces of,
2. Activate the Shape Builder tool,
3. Choose the color you want to fill with,
4. Click each area you want to fill...

[image]

A few notes on the Shape Builder tool;

- It will, by default, only detect *closed* spaces, so if there are gaps it won't be able to create the shape to fill. You can double click the icon in the toolbar and enable "Gap Detection" to give you a bit of leeway here but it's best to try and start of with closed areas to begin with.
- The tool only works on the object that are currently selected, so if you have multiple overlapping shapes, make sure the correct objects are selected (your artwork has distinct foreground and background shapes for example, so only select and work on one at a time).

Comment: Hello Cai! I try to  do that but unfortunate, the fill color acts as outline only. can you please help me ?

Comment: You tried the Shape Builder tool? Did it create the correct shapes on the inside triangles and did you set the fill color on those shapes?

Comment: Yes, when I try it. the fill color only acts as outline?who you mind yo check AI file?

Comment: I doubt my answer will change by looking at the file. If you're getting an "outline" after using Shape Builder then either you're selecting the lines themselves (rather than spaces between) or you're giving the shapes a stroke rather than a fill.

Comment: I will try again, by the way where can I find the GAP Detection?

Comment: Double click the Shape Builder icon in the toolbar and you'll get an options dialog, you can enable it from there

Comment: My problem now is since I am coloring the inner triangle after putting fill there are some overlaps with black lines? is it can be fxed/

Comment: @Dave you'll have to share a screenshot or something because I don't know what you mean

Comment: I alreay got it, I adjust the layers! Thank you so much Cai!!

Comment: Why is it that When I export the image it s something like this

https://imgur.com/a/QoDxF

it is very small but image size is 5000

Comment: it should look like this https://imgur.com/a/wgy4a

Comment: That depends on how you export the image, but that is beyond the scope of this question. I suggest you search through older question here first or read through https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/user-guide.html and then ask a new question if you're still stuck

Comment: Hi Cai! Yes I will take a look at that, Thanks Really Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are probably have something that looks like this on the left of your screen:

[image]

The black colour is the outline and the white colour with the red line is the fill. In this case, the red line indicates that there is no colour set.

Select your triangle, then double click the box with the red line and select a colour. This should fill your triangle.

If this doesn't work, then the lines may not be connected as one shape. You'll have to connect the lines to make a closed shape.

Comment: Hi! How to make a close shape? I already do that but it is still that way, the fill color is acting like a outline

Comment: @DaveManuel have you tried the flip button? It's the two arrows to the top right of the boxes?

Comment: what 2 arrows? I update my question with another picture to show the problem

Comment: @DaveManuel Okay, I know now what the problem is. Sometimes, when people sell their designs, they create outlines of their work. That way people can upscale and downscale their work without messing with line thickness and all that... So you basically have very thin objects. You'll have to draw triangles behind the lines and colour those. Then you can get the effect you need.

Comment: so what should I do? What do you mean draw?  I can share to you gusy the AI file

Comment: @Chris no you dont either use live paint bucket or shapebuilder. And no they dont sometimes do this some stock sites demand that you do it!

Comment: ohh so you mean I do it by my self?

Comment: @DaveManuel Yeah. I would personally make new shapes behind the existing shapes, but as JooJaa says, you can do it with live paint or shapebuilder.

Comment: OMG I waste my 15 dollars for this

Comment: Can you please tell me some more details about that? I am ttally new with ilustartor

Comment: @DaveManuel Check the answer that Cai wrote. He shows it better.

Comment: Where that wrote?

Comment: @DaveManuel https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107644/115689